# cropping an UIImage to a new aspect ratio

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiimage, crop

i want to crop an UIImage to get a new aspect ratio...

bounds is a CGRect with `(0,0, newwidth, newhigh)`...

```
- (UIImage *)croppedImage:(UIImage *)myImage :(CGRect)bounds {
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(myImage.CGImage, bounds);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGSize asd =  croppedImage.size;
    return croppedImage;
}
```

with the call:

```
[workImage croppedImage: workImage: CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeigh)];
```

after that the "workimage" have the same size as before...

what could be wrong?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you aren't altering the current image as this seems to be a category method on `UIImage`. You are creating a new image and returning it. So what will work is this,

```
workImage = [workImage croppedImage: workImage: CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeigh)];
```

However I think the method is better named like this, (assuming it as a category method on `UIImage`)

```
- (UIImage *)croppedImageWithRect:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, bounds);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGSize asd =  croppedImage.size;
    return croppedImage;
}
```

This way you will call it like this,

```
workImage = [workImage croppedImageWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeigh)];
```

And as a side note, don't use methods like `croppedImage::`. It is better to name all parameters like say `croppedImage:rect:`.